# Loop over first three items of a list in Rules

Tags: 7, rules

I have a list and need to loop only over the first 3 elements of that list in Rules, but I cannot find the option to do this. It seems to be more complicated than I had thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) so that you can add "conditions" between " rule actions". After that you can create a variable which iterates and use that to stop after the third elements.

Comment: thank you I already did it =) that conditional rules should be added to the rule's core

Comment: @SsouLlesS Hi, how did you stop the loop with a condition? There is no stop action in rules loop. Thank you.